# CSS Media Print Query

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I have a working `@media print` query in `modal`. Then I added a chart that has also a PRINT functionality.  When I tried the PRINT in chart, it is not displaying anything in Chrome Print Dialog. I am thinking that because of the `@media print`.

How can I add same functionality of `modal` in my `chart`?

CSS Media Print:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto; 
    margin: 3mm;
    margin-right: 57mm;
    margin-left: 57mm
  }

  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #admissionSlip * {
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  #chart * {
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  #mainPage * {
    display: none;
  }
  #printBtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .modal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 550px;
    visibility: visible;
    /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .modal-dialog {
    visibility: visible !important;
    /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  li {
    page-break-after: auto;
  }

  /* Chart */

  .panel {
    visibility: visible !important;
    /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about if you remove `body * {visibility: hidden;}` ?

Comment: @KenjiMukai, it works on chart but when I tried to click the print in my modal part, the display got messy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by not so good idea, but it did what I need.

I separate the `css` file of `media print` of `chart` and `modal` and reference it on each `html` file.

I know that it is not a good idea and that's probably not a best practice but it did what I needed. Thanks.